# Is it almost a palindrome?

Tags: javascript

This problem is pretty simple, if a string is a palindrome (or is empty), return true. if removing one letter from one index in the string makes it a palindrome return true. otherwise return false.

My code, which I believe works:

```js
const isQuasiPalindrome = str => {
  if(!str || str.length < 2) return true
  const chars = str.split('')
  return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars, false)
}
const isQuasiPalindromeWorker = (chars, isRemoved) => {
  if(chars.length === 0) return false
  for(i = 0, j = chars.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if(chars[i] !== chars[j]) {
      if(isRemoved) return false
      const left = chars.filter((_,k) => k !== i)
      const right = chars.filter((_,l) => l !== j)
      return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(left, true) 
        || isQuasiPalindromeWorker(right, true)
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

(There's an even better answer that is less space-demanding)

Now, here's what I had after maybe 5-10 minutes:

```js
const isQuasiPalindrome = str => {
  if(!str || str.length < 2) return true
  const chars = str.split('')
  return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars, false)
}
const isQuasiPalindromeWorker = (chars, isRemoved) => {
  if(chars.length === 0) return false
  for(i = 0, j = chars.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if(chars[i] !== chars[j]) {
      if(isRemoved) return false
      return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars.filter((_,k) => k !== i)
, true) 
        || isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars.filter((_,l) => l !== j)
, true)
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

For some reason that version doesn't work. *why* doesn't it work?

Here's a version with console logs to help demonstrate how it is failing:

```js
const isQuasiPalindrome = str => {
  const chars = str.split('')
  return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars, false)
}
const isQuasiPalindromeWorker = (chars, isRemoved) => {
  console.log('chars', chars)
  if(chars.length === 0) return false
  for( i = 0, j = chars.length - 1; i < j; i++, j-- ) {
    console.log(i,j)
    if(chars[i] !== chars[j]) {
      if(isRemoved) return false
      console.log(chars.filter((_,l) => l !== i), chars.filter((_,l) => l !== j))
      return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars.filter((_,k) => k !== i), true) || isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars.filter((_,l) => l !== j), true)
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Sample result:

```
isQuasiPalindrome('racecars')
chars 
Array(8) [ "r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r", "s" ]
debugger eval code:6:11
0 7 debugger eval code:9:13
Array(7) [ "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r", "s" ]
 
Array(7) [ "r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r" ]
debugger eval code:12:15
chars 
Array(7) [ "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r", "s" ]
debugger eval code:6:11
0 6 debugger eval code:9:13
chars 
Array(7) [ "r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "s" ]
debugger eval code:6:11
0 6 debugger eval code:9:13
false
```

My original version only saves 2 lines of code, and definitely makes it less legible. But I wasted a *lot* of time figuring out why my code was failing here, and frankly, I see how it is failing but still not why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const isQuasiPalindrome = str => {
  if(!str || str.length < 2) return true
  const chars = str.split('')
  return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars, false)
}
const isQuasiPalindromeWorker = (chars, isRemoved) => {
  if(chars.length === 0) return false
  for(let i = 0, j = chars.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    if(chars[i] !== chars[j]) {
      if(isRemoved) return false
      return isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars.filter((_,k) => k !== i)
, true) 
        || isQuasiPalindromeWorker(chars.filter((_,l) => l !== j)
, true)
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

I've edited the failing code snippet by adding the `let` keyword in the for loop. This should return `true` for `racecars`.

Without the `let` keyword, i and j are implicitly declared as global variables. Once `isisQuasiPalindromeWorker` has run, by the time
`chars.filter((_,l) => l !== j` is executed, `j` has had its value overwritten.

Comment: ooh, so there was a memory collision -- can you describe what the collision was more precisely please? (clearly, that does work)

Comment: @robertotomás `i=0` sets the global variable `i` to `0`, so recursively calling the function will modify this global state instead of having a local variable for each call.